# Using early_printk with trace_printk

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

How can I use `trace_printk` in place of `printk` in early boot code. I tried with statement `trace_printk("%s",__FUNCTION__);` in `start_kernel` function but no output.Same statement with `printk` works fine. I am thinking its because `printk` works with `early_printk` but `trace_printk` cannot be used with `early_printk`. Is there any way to use `trace_printk` with `early_printk` since `printk` has a lot of overhead.

Comment: The way `trace_printk()` works is, it does not output to the console. Instead, it writes to the ftrace ring buffer and can be read via the trace file. `trace_printk()` requires setup before you can directly use it.

 [Refer](https://lwn.net/Articles/365835/)  lwn article for more information.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ? It's not entirely clear from your question.

Comment: You also has to be sure that tracing system is initialized. `start_kernel()` is quite early for that I suppose.